# how to integrate barcode scanner in phonegap in android platform?

Tags: html, cordova

I want to integrate a "*barcodescanner*"-feature into my PhoneGap Application, but facing problem while running my app "`class not found or applicationcontent is missing in applicationstatus.`

Here is my `index.html` file

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

         <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

         function onDeviceReady(){

         }
          cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
      alert("hello");
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
   );
          cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.encode(cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.Encode.TEXT_TYPE, "http://www.nytimes.com", function(success) {
            alert("encode success: " + success);
          }, function(fail) {
            alert("encoding failed: " + fail);
          }
        );

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn" onclick="scan()">scan</button>
     <button id="btn1" onclick="encode()">edit text</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: where are your scan() and encode() functions, I can't see them

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it and works fine :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="scanBarcode()">Scan</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script>
    function scanBarcode(){

cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
  }, 
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
 );
}

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue with your code is that you don't have functions scan() and encode() to bind to your buttons thus nothing will happen.

Comment: thanku ... finally i learn my mistek and got a good answer .. thanku.. :)

Comment: You can accept the answer if you think it solved your issue ;)

Comment: @MidouCloud , maybe you should expose your issue instead of downvoting

Comment: Sorry but i see before this same answer on other sites and still not working for me and other people. First is "cordova is not defined" but i put cordova before the other scripts. Im testing this on both emulator and phone. Also i added "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" to my config.xml.  I still dont know why is not working. Sorry for the downvote, i will change my vote later.

Comment: You should create a topic and show your console errors if you have or any other details.

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of Phonegap and the version of the plugin?
Is your `barcodescanner.js` well loaded?

Do you have this permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```