# Barcode Scanner Phonegap not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to include the barcode scanner plugin for phonegap (phonegap 5.1.1) and I can't make it work (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)

1. First of all, I installed the plugin running:

   phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
2. Then I have a javascript function:

```js
function leerBarCode(){
    //navigator.notification.alert("LLega a leerBarCode", alertDismissed, "Mensaje", "OK");
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
        alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    }, function (error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    });
}
```

When I click over a button that calls to this function, it doesn't launch the camera. Please, can you help me?

Comment: I answered a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610672/how-to-integrate-barcode-scanner-in-phonegap-in-android-platform/31611880#31611880